# How to know when a std::thread has finished in c++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stdthread

I am just learning how to use `std::thread` in c++11. Basically, I have a long list of data (imagine a for loop between 0-15000) and 1568 threads in the hardware I am using. I want a separate thread to process each sample. I understand how to create the first 1568 threads, it works fine. But once I reach the N_thread+1 sample, I then want to check to see if there are any available threads. If there are, send that data sample to that thread. Each thread is sent to a mutex-locked function which unlocks at the end. Perhaps I have misunderstood how threads work and cannot do things this way? Or perhaps there is a better threading/CPU assigning library that can help?

As I said, I can get to the point where the 1568 threads are created and run and join, and the end results are good. Just need a bit more information.

This is my main

```
int main(){
  cout<<"In main"<<endl;
  CSVReaderUpdatedStructure reader("data.csv");
  vector<STMDataPacket> DataList = reader.GetData();

  thread_pool Pool(THREAD_COUNT);
  auto startT0 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
   for(unsigned s=0; s<DataList.size()-1; s++){
      cout<<"analysing sample "<<s<<endl;
      auto done = Pool.add_task([s= s, Sample= DataList[s], t_inf = time_info,wf=writefile, f=factor]{GetDMWPulses(s, Sample, t_inf, wf,f);});
      done.wait();

    }

  auto stop = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  cout<<"pulses "<<pulses.size()<<endl;
  auto duration = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(stop - startT0); 
  cout <<"time for MWD full process = "<< duration.count() <<" microseconds "<< endl;

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: Unless you talk about a very specialized hardware, 1568 threads is likely too much. Also, you need a thread pool for what you want to achieve. `std::thread` could be a building block for a thread pool, but alone it wouldn't suffice.

Comment: What you want sounds like a thread pool.  You can either make one yourself or use a library to get one.  If you google thread pool you'll get a lot of information.

Comment: Thread creation and destruction are time consuming. Generally, you want to use a thread pool which don't require thread creation/destruction and just use the same threads. VS uses this technique implementing `std::async` and will use CPU resources much more effectively though there can be issues with `thread_local` as these are difficult to handle properly with thread pools.

Comment: There is nothing in std::thread to check how many threads your hardware supports. You need a platform-specific API, or a third party library that wraps one (such as TBB).

Comment: Re, "Each thread is sent to a mutex locked function which unlocks at the end." That almost sounds as if you want all of the work done by a thread to be done with the mutex locked. But that would mean that there could never be more than one thread working at any given time, which sounds like it is _not_ what you want.

Comment: If you're trying to do _multiprocessing_ (i.e., using multiple threads to speed up a computation on a multi-CPU machine), then you'll need to minimize the amount of time that any given thread keeps any given mutex locked. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law

Comment: Sounds like using threads for this is the wrong solution to the problem. You should use a thread pool with only as many threads as you have cores (unless you luckily have 1568 cores in your machine).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably don't want 1568 threads.  You want 1568+ tasks, maybe.

You probably want a thread pool.  TBB has a thread pool, and is available on almost every platform.

Writing your own thread pool isn't that hard.  Here is a sketch of one:

```
template<class T>
struct threadsafe_queue {
  optional<T> pop() {
    auto l = lock();
    cv.wait( l, [&]{
      return abort || !data.empty();
    });
    if (abort) return {};
    T retval = std::move(data.front());
    data.pop();
    return retval;
  }
  void push( T in ) {
    auto l = lock();
    data.push( std::move(in) );
    cv.notify_one();
  }
  void abort_queue() {
    auto l = lock();
    abort = true;
    cv.notify_all();
  }
private:
  mutable std::mutex m;
  std::condition_variable cv;
  std::queue<T> data;
  bool abort = false;

  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock() const {
    return std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(m);
  }
};

struct thread_pool {
  template<class F, class R=typename std::decay< typename std::result_of< F&() >::type>::type>
  auto add_task( F&& f )
  -> std::future< R >
  {
     std::packaged_task<R()> task( std::forward<F>(f) );
     auto retval = task.get_future();
     tasks.push( std::packaged_task<void()>(std::move(task)) );
     return retval;
  }

  void start_thread( std::size_t N=1 )
  {
    if (shutdown) return;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
      threads.emplace_back( [this]{
        while (true)
        {
          if(shutdown) return;
          auto task = tasks.pop();
          if (!task)
            return;
          (*task)();
        }
      } );
    }
  }
  void cleanup() {
    shutdown = true;
    tasks.abort_queue();
    for (auto&& t:threads)
      t.join();
    threads.clear();
  }
  ~thread_pool() {
    cleanup();
  }

  thread_pool():thread_pool( std::thread::hardware_concurrency() ) {}
  explicit thread_pool( std::size_t N ) {
    start_thread(N);
  }
private:
  threadsafe_queue<std::packaged_task<void()>> tasks;
  std::vector<std::thread> threads;
  std::atomic<bool> shutdown = false;
};
```

now create a `thread_pool`.

Shove tasks into it.  Get futures out.

Have the worker tasks increment a `std::atomic<unsigned int>` and wait for it to hit max, or do something fancier.

```
struct counting_barrier {
  explicit counting_barrier( std::size_t n ):count(n) {}
  void operator--() {
    --count;
    if (count <= 0)
    {
       std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(m);
       cv.notify_all();
    }
  }
  void wait() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(m);
    cv.wait( l, [&]{ return count <= 0; } );
  }
private:
  std::mutex m;
  std::condition_variable cv;
  std::atomic<std::ptrdiff_t> count = 0;
};
```

Create a `counting_barrier  barrier( 15000 )` or whatever.  Threads when done can `--barrier` (it is thread safe).  The main thread can `barrier.wait()` and it will be woken up when 15000 `--` have been called.

The above code may have typos, but the design is sound.  For industrial strength use, you'll also want to have a better shutdown procedure.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/31edb8f14a7e67ce).

If you don't have optional or boost optional, use this:

```
template<class T>
struct optional {
  T* get() { return static_cast<T*>( static_cast<void*>( & data ) ); };
  T const* get() const { return static_cast<T*>( static_cast<void*>( & data ) ); };

  T& operator*() & { return *get(); }
  T&& operator*() && { return std::move(*get()); }
  T const& operator*() const & { return *get(); }
  T const&& operator*() const&& { return std::move(*get()); }

  explicit operator bool() const { return engaged; }
  bool has_value() const { return (bool)*this; }
  template< class U >
  T value_or( U&& default_value ) const& {
    if (*this) return **this;
    return std::forward<U>(default_value);
  }
  template< class U >
  T value_or( U&& default_value ) && {
    if (*this) return std::move(**this);
    return std::forward<U>(default_value);
  }

  optional(T const& t) {
    emplace(t);
  }
  optional(T&& t) {
    emplace(std::move(t));
  }
  optional() = default;
  optional(optional const& o) {
    if (o) {
      emplace( *o );
    }
  }
  optional(optional && o) {
    if (o) {
      emplace( std::move(*o) );
    }
  }
  optional& operator=(optional const& o) & {
    if (!o) {
      reset();
    } else if (*this) {
      **this = *o;
    } else {
      emplace( *o );
    }
    return *this;
  }
  optional& operator=(optional && o) & {
    if (!o) {
      reset();
    } else if (*this) {
      **this = std::move(*o);
    } else {
      emplace( std::move(*o) );
    }
    return *this;
  }
  template<class...Args>
  T& emplace(Args&&...args) {
    if (*this) reset();
    ::new( static_cast<void*>(&data) ) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    engaged = true;
    return **this;
  }
  void reset() {
    if (*this) {
      get()->~T();
      engaged = false;
    }
  }
  ~optional() { reset(); }
private:
  using storage = typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>::type;
  bool engaged = false;
  storage data;
};
```

note that this optional isn't industrial strength; I literally wrote it and didn't test it.  It is missing many industrial strength features that a real optional has.  But you can drop a real optional in its place and get pretty much the same or better behavior, so it can be used if you lack one.

```
counting_barrier barrier(100);
thread_pool p(10);
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
  p.add_task([&barrier,i]{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << i << ",";
    std::cout << ss.str();
    --barrier;
  });
}
barrier.wait();
std::cout << "\n";
auto done1 = p.add_task([]{ std::cout << "hello" << std::endl; });
done1.wait();
auto done2 = p.add_task([]{ std::cout << "world" << std::endl; });
done2.wait();
```

Comment: "You don't want 1568 threads.". Perhaps *you* don't want 1568 threads. I've tested machines with more hardware threads than that. It seems OP has one of those.

Comment: @n.m. Sure.  And if I'm wrong about that, the rest of the answer still works and solves their problem.  :)

Comment: Hi, going back to this now-if I want to add a function eg. void Finder(int x, float y) to the queue how would I do that in a main function elsewhere?

Comment: `add_task( [x=x_expression, y=y_expression]{ Finder(x,y); } )`, where `x_expression` is an expression you run to calculate what you want for `x` and `y_expression` is an expression you run to calculate what you want for `y`.  Ie: `add_task( [x=-1, y=3.14]{ Finder(x,y); } )`

Comment: thanks, i tried running the code, it would not let me use the "atomics":  error: use of deleted function âstd::atomic<bool>::atomic(const std::atomic<bool>&)â so i tried without but that caused: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::future_error'
terminate called recursively

Comment: @smid Well, [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/87a01555d83f2d59) works.  There was like 2 typos I had to fix.

Comment: ok, yeah that seems to work now. I'm still not sure how to manage this for a larger number of threads. I havent yet put in the counting barrier, would this be defined in the main function, and incremented in the threading function or just in the main?

Comment: At the moment it seems to get to the number of threads "N" then pauses....i guess its "waiting" but I dont think there's anything in there to reassign threads to the next sample to analyse once they are free....if that make sense. So if I have 50 threads for exampl and I want to analyse 100 samples, the first 50 is easy to imagine then once those one thread is finished i want sample 51 to be done on that thread....i guess the something like the counting barrier is needed

Comment: @smid Fixed.  I needed an optional to do it cleanly, and you wanted C++11.  So I wrote an optional, or you can use boost::optional.  I forgot a while loop, and for clean shutdown I needed to add the ability to abort the queue, and to abort the queue cleanly I wanted an optional to return from `pop`.  :)

Comment: thanks, seems to work now as in no faults and runs through all samples. The time taken , however, doesnt seem to change significantly no matter how many threads i choose....prehaps its just that my code cannot be improved by threading but i feel there should be some change

Comment: I have no idea what your hardware is.  So I cannot advise.

Comment: lscpu:
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                56
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-55
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    14
Socket(s):             2
NUMA node(s):          2
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 79
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 v4 @ 2.40GHz
Stepping:              1
CPU MHz:               2423.343
CPU max MHz:           3300.0000
CPU min MHz:           1200.0000

Comment: Ah.  You are memory bandwidth starved as a guess.  Slice the data up so that a given thread processes a bunch of consecutive data, instead of getting random pieces here and there.  You can also look at your specs for how many MB/s your RAM can handle and compare it to the rate you are solving the problem; that can tell you if there is room for more performance improvement with more compute or not
.

Comment: ah yes I think you are right, i just did "top" and see I am using up all the CPU %....although the mem % is not greater than 5%. I guess i need to scale back my algorithim if i want time improvments or change it as you suggest

Comment: If you are using all CPU and not much memory, then there is hope.  Break the data down into ~4500 pieces (slightly less than 3 times the number of threads, say).  Have a task do an entire piece (more than one "line" or "row").  See if that does better.

Comment: I am trying to create 3 tasks, as you mentione. I had a play with the "fork()" options but this produced some confussing results. I dont want parent/child strucutre....i guess this is not the best way to run it. I can look at "htop" and see that with the current code (that described above) 400 tasks on are used. I tried doing some forks to see how this changed and i can see that it does create the extra tasks which is what I want but prehaps there is a better way? I see lots of options with c++17, I am thinking maybe to upgrade to that but I would rather use what I have if I can.

Comment: @smid I don't understand why you are calling fork.  You have 15000 elements.  And ~1500 threads.  So each thread is going to handle ~10 elements.  Maybe some elements will be faster/slower.  Solution 1: each thread handles ~10 elements in a row.  Solution 2: each thread handles ~3-4 elements in a row, then goes back and grabs another task from the queue, running ~3 times.  Current solution: each thread handles 1 element, then goes back, running ~10 times.  I'm saying we can reduce contention (of the queue) and improve memory locality (same thread, adjacent) by doing tasks in bigger bundles.

Comment: `done.wait();` -- that waits until the task is done.  You do this before you start a 2nd task.  Then you wait for that to be done before starting a 3rd task.  That seems like a bad plan.

Comment: @smid: add your edit/clarification to your question, not into the answer

Comment: I have added my main for discussion. That data list is the 15000 samples. I have now 1500 threads for simplicity. So I should add in a loop/while somewhere to send 10 samples in to the add_task at that point then increment to the next 10?

Comment: I have added an example of properly using `counting_barrier` and running 100 tasks on 10 threads in the answer above, including a link to a live example.  @smid editing an answer with a response is not correct.  Really, at this point, consider asking another question using the [ask a question] button.

Comment: yes, it was a mistake I meant to add the code to the question. I will try this now and see how things turn out/ Thanks